# View results to show results in language of current page, but if no translation available show original language?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I need a view to display results based on the following:

- if the content has a translation available in the language of the current page, show that one
- if the content DOES NOT have a translation available in the language of the current page, then show the original source of the content

The same content item can be shown only once, regardless of language (i.e. if the content is shown in english then it cannot also be shown in spanish in the same view).

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Additional information.

Most* content is sourced in English and some of it is translated to Spanish. There are three pieces of content, however, who's original language is Spanish and do not have an English translation.

So, when viewing the aggregation page in Spanish, I should see the three Spanish articles as well as all of the other English articles, but I should see the English articles who have a translation in Spanish have their Spanish translations rendered. I should also see all of the English articles who don't have Spanish translations.

When viewing in English, I should see all of the articles in English with the exception of the three Spanish articles who should be rendered in Spanish (since it's the only available language for those articles).

EDIT: Image showing configuration of the view currently.

[image]

EDIT: Image showing available filter options for Original language.

[image]

Comment: see the second option in this comment https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261401/repeated-elements-in-translations-of-a-block-view/261444#comment320147_261444

Comment: I'm missing this filter option: Translation language (= Content language selected for page). The only one I see is Translation language (= Interface text language selected for page).

Comment: Both are the same unless *Customize Content language detection to differ from Interface text language detection settings* is enabled in language configuration.

Comment: Hm okay. That is not enabled for our site so that shouldn't be affecting things. I'll post a picture of my view configuration, as I followed the steps in that linked issue and I'm still not seeing all entities showing in the expected translation. Still just seeing the three Spanish articles when viewing the page in Spanish instead of all of the articles showing English and also those three Spanish articles showing Spanish....

Comment: For the second option you have to filter the original language.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far 4k4. I posted an image of the available values for the "Original language" filter option. Not sure which one to pick. I don't think this works for my use case, as the original language of the content is not always the same. Some contents original language is english, but some content's original language is spanish. If I set the filter value to one or the other, then that would not actually display all the content I'm expecting to see, I think?

Comment: I also clarified my use case in the first EDIT.

Comment: Then you have to filter Default translation = TRUE, so that you only get one row for each node which then gets translated to the detected current interface language as set in the middle column of the view.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. Thanks for helping a brother out. That is exactly what I needed to make this use case work.